# Jquery: How do I get the user's input as they type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to get the user's input to be able to validate it and see if it is a key that I want to appear or use. I don't want the full value of what is in the input, just the specific key they are entering.

I have done it in Javascript by using this code but it does not work the same in Jquery. Thanks!

```
<input type="text" id="a">

$("#a").on('input', function(e){
    var charval = String.fromCharCode(e.Keycode);
    alert(charval);
});
```

The alert should show the key that was pressed.

DEMO:

```js
$("#a").on('input', function(e){
 var charval = String.fromCharCode(e.Keycode);
 alert(charval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a">
```

Comment: check the https://jsfiddle.net/qm7zka87/2/

Comment: And what does it show? this appears to be a typo to me.

Comment: the input event also doesn't have access to the key that was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```js
document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('out').textContent = e.keyCode;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="f">
<p id="out">Hi</p>
```

You'll see keyCode of the last button pressed. You can also add an alert inside a listener if you wish so.

Answer (score 0):

Change e.keycode to e.which

```js
$("#a").on("keypress", function(e){
var charval = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    alert(charval);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed your code to work :

```
$("#a").on('keyup', function(e){
      var charval = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
      alert(charval);
});
```